# how to update current user email and password (both in user node and authentication) in firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, email, firebase

I am trying to update my user details page(username,phno,email and password).Cant able to update the email field,incase it gets updated means not in both(user and authentication).Any hlp wil be appreciated..plz code in swift2.2

here my *userDeatilsViewController*

```
class UserDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

var user:UserDetails?
let userRegister = UserInfo()
var user_name:String?
var first_name:String?
var last_name:String?
var ph_no:String?
var e_mail:String?
var pass_word:String?
var activeField: UITextField?

@IBOutlet var Username: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Firstname: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Lastname: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var phNo: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var password: UITextField!

var rootRef: FIRDatabaseReference! {
    return FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    let userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
    userRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot)  in

        for userInfo in snapshot.children {
            self.user = UserDetails(snapshot: userInfo as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            print(self.user)
        }
        if let user = self.user{
            self.Username.text = user.username
            self.Firstname.text = user.firstname
            self.Lastname.text = user.lastname
            self.email.text = user.email
            self.phNo.text = user.phno
        }
    })

    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
@IBAction func reset(sender: AnyObject) {

    let userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")

    if Username.text == "" {
        Username.text = "enter title"
    } else {
        user_name = Username.text
    }

    if Firstname.text == ""{
        Firstname.text = "Firstname Missing"
    } else {
        first_name = Firstname.text
    }

    if Lastname.text == "" {
        Lastname.text = "Lastname Missing"
    } else {
        last_name = Lastname.text
    }

    if phNo.text == "" {
        phNo.text = "Phno Missing"
    } else {
        ph_no = phNo.text
    }

    if email.text == "" {
        email.text = "email Missing"
    } else {
      if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
          user.updateEmail(email.text!, completion: { (error) in

            if let error = error{
              print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
              let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "Update Email", message: "email Updated", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
              alertView.show()
            }
         })
         self.e_mail = self.email.text
         print(self.e_mail)
      }
    }

    let updatenote = UserDetails(username: user_name!, firstname: first_name!, lastname: last_name!, email: e_mail!, phno: ph_no!)

    print(updatenote)

    let key = user!.ref!.key
    print(key)

    let updateRef = rootRef.child("/users/\(key)")

    updateRef.updateChildValues(updatenote.toAnyObject())
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: it didnt helps..tried before..first of all have to update email only..First i retrieved all user details in a page except password text field..so if needs to change the password (separate button action) otherwise only have update the other fields.

Comment: if using above mentioned sample means... password string becomes nil..?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is these lines:

```
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
     user.updateEmail(email.text!, completion: { (error) in
```

the 'user' is a copy of the current user, not a reference to the current user, so when you update the user, you are not updating the actual current user.

Try this code to update the users email address - remember also that to update the email, the user must have logged in recently. i.e. you must be logged in as the user to change the email.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.updateEmail(email.text!) { (error) in
  // ...
}
```

Note that I could be totally wrong...

Comment: ya..it getting update..but as you said ..it needs recent login..?so for every time i tries to update means..need to login again and again..?while search regarding this...doc says to reauthenticate...so my next question is..how to reauthenticate the user..

Comment: @tecE That's covered in the Firebase guide [Managing Users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users)